# Downloading Javascript bundle never starts and gives me error

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm-install, expo

When I run my React-Native application it does not start and the download of the JavaScript bundle also never starts. I'm running my application on expo.

How I can solve this error?

Here is screenshot of command prompt:

[image]

Comment: It happens right after project init or have you done some changes already?

Comment: you npm installed?